# ${\frac {\partial^{2} u}{\partial {x}^{2}}} +{\frac {\partial ^{2} u}{\partial {y}^{2}}} =0$ with one boundary at infinity

Tags: differential-equations, symbolic, boundary-condition-at-infinity

Is there a trick to make Mathematica solve

$${\frac {\partial^{2}  u}{\partial {x}^{2}}}  +{\frac 
{\partial ^{2} u}{\partial {y}^{2}}} =0$$ with one boundary condition at $\infty$?

Boundary conditions are

$$
\begin{align*}
u \left( 0,y \right) &=\sin \left( y \right) \\
u \left( x,0 \right) &=0 \\
u \left( x,a \right) &=0\\
u \left( \infty ,y \right) &=0
\end{align*}
$$

Maple can solve this analytically, but one must tell it to assume $a>0$. But I can't get Mathematica 11.2 to solve it. Even when $a$ is given a numerical value.  This is last problem listed [here](https://www.12000.org/my_notes/pde_in_CAS/pde_in_cas.htm)

Mathematica can solve it only by removing the $\infty$ boundary condition and making it finite.

Here is the code

```
ClearAll[x,y,a]
ode=D[u[x,y],{x,2}]+D[u[x,y],{y,2}]==0;
bc={u[x,0]==0,u[x,a]==0,u[0,y]==Sin[y],u[Infinity,y]==0};
Assuming[a>0,DSolve[{ode,bc},u[x,y],{x,y}]]
```

I think `Assuming[a>0` above is not even used by `DSolve`. Also with `a` being numerical, it does not solve it:

```
ClearAll[x,y,a]
a=2;
ode=D[u[x,y],{x,2}]+D[u[x,y],{y,2}]==0;
bc={u[x,0]==0,u[x,a]==0,u[0,y]==Sin[y],u[Infinity,y]==0};
DSolve[{ode,bc},u[x,y],{x,y}]
```

Maple 2017 solves it, and gives this

```
ode:=diff(u(x,y),x$2)+diff(u(x,y),y$2)=0;
bc:=u(x,0)=0, u(x,a)=0, u(0,y)=sin(y), u(infinity,y)=0;
sol:=pdsolve({ode, bc}, u(x,y)) assuming a>0;
```

$$
u \left( x,y \right) =\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }2\,{\frac { \left( -1
 \right) ^{1+n}\pi\,\sin \left( a \right) n}{{\pi}^{2}{n}^{2}-{a}^{2}}
\sin \left( {\frac {\pi\,yn}{a}} \right) {{\rm e}^{-{\frac {\pi\,xn}{a
}}}}}
$$

Screen shot

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Any one knows of a trick to make Mathematica solve this symbolically?

Comment: Perhaps, Mathematica is having difficulties, because the initial and boundary conditions are inconsistent.  It is, of course, possible to Fourier-decompose the PDE in `y`, but the resulting solution does not converge uniformly.

Comment: @bbgodfrey oh, that was just me changing the PDE while playing around with it. The original one had `Sin[y]` there. But M still can't solve it. I should correct this now. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using the symbolic boundary condition

```
u[t, y] == 0
```

instead of the infinite one, and then taking the limit $$ t \to \infty,$$ *inside* the sum seems to do the trick for me.

```
ClearAll[x, y, a]
ode = D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y], {y, 2}] == 0;
bc = {u[x, 0] == 0, u[x, a] == 0, u[0, y] == Sin[y], u[t, y] == 0};
sol = Assuming[a > 0, DSolve[{ode, bc}, u[x, y], {x, y}]];
expr = (u[x, y] /. sol)[[1]][[1]];
limexpr = 
  Assuming[ a > 0 && K[1] > 0, Limit[expr, t -> \[Infinity]]];
Inactivate[Sum[limexpr, {K[1], 1, \[Infinity]}]]
```

This gives $$\underset{K[1]=1}{\overset{\infty }{\sum }}-\frac{2 \pi  \sin (a) (-1)^{K[1]} K[1] e^{-\frac{\pi  x K[1]}{a}} \sin \left(\frac{\pi  y K[1]}{a}\right)}{\pi ^2 K[1]^2-a^2}$$

Comment: Thanks. btw, the original PDE had `sin` not `cos`. This does not affect your method. Just wanted to point I made change to the PDE now.

Comment: I've updated the solution to reflect this :)